# In Postgres, how to share the server along with the database that I created using pgadmin 4

Tags: database, postgresql, connection, pgadmin-4

I want to grant access of db to my friend,I have create role and grant him the access using this sql script and It ran successfully

`-- CREATE ROLE friend_username WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'friend_password'; GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my_db TO friend_username; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_db TO  friend_username; GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO friend_username;`

now what should I do from my side as I have granted him the new role, and friend_username would be his username. Provide me with the steps that how he can add to my shared server and db.

Comment: 1) Read [Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html). 2) Then read [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).